# Is it possible to query a value (or a value set) with cassandra even if we don't know the key (or key range) in advance?

Tags: database, cassandra, p2p, distributed-computing

I am going to express the idea in SQL:

```
SELECT key,value
FROM table1
WHERE value > 10
```

Or do we always need to know the key?

Comment: Did you check secondary indexes? http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-cassandra-07-secondary-indexes

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you can use secondary indexes which are available since version 0.7 of casssandra. 
You might also checkout the following answer: [Cassandra and Secondary-Indexes, how do they work internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418181/cassandra-and-secondary-indexes-how-do-they-work-internally)

it is recommended to use secondary indexes only for low-cardinality columns, which means for columns which do not have many different values (e.g. columns like 'status' or 'priority' which have usually only a handful different values like 'high', 'medium', 'low').

In case you are using Hector as your cassandra client you can find information here how to use them:
https://github.com/rantav/hector/wiki/User-Guide

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course, for example, you can use *

```
select * from CF where value = 10
```

If you use the Hector API (e.g. CqlQuery), you can get a list of rows back from this query.

Note, currently for secondary indexes, you must have at least one equality conditional, so your query with just *value > 10* would not work. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356882/how-to-search-secondary-index-in-cassandra-without-equality)